# Manually ask user to access photos or camera

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering how to put up the "This app would like to access your photos/camera: Don't allow, Allow" on the screen when a button is pressed. I've got code to check if photos or camera is enabled, but not something that brings up the action to allow or not allow it. How do I do this for each (photos and camera)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Obj C

```
-(void)showImagePicker
{
    if ([AVCaptureDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessForMediaType: completionHandler:)]) {
            [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (granted) {
    // Here you can implement your functions.
                    } else {
    // This condition executes when the user taps Don't Allow option on the alertVeiw. This alert is an one time alert. so you may need to reset the privacy and location settings in your device settings.
                        [self cancel];
                    }
                });
            }];
        } else {
            [self cancel];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following when the button mentioned of is tapped:

Obj-C:

```
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus) {
    if (authorizationStatus == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // Add your custom logic here
    }
}];
```

Swift:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (authorizationStatus) -> Void in
    if authorizationStatus == .Authorized {
        // Add your custom logic here
    }
}
```

The system pop-up for permission to access the photo library will come up if needed.

Comment: If I already the app to access (photos for example), will the pop-up show up again if I delete the app from the simulator and redownload it?

Comment: It should for a device. The behavior on a simulator might not be guaranteed to be consistent. I would suggest testing this on a device.

Comment: I just tested it on a device and it doesn't show the pop-up after I deleted the app and ran it again. The values for the photos and camera were the same as before it was deleted.

Comment: @smecperson That's normal behavior.

Comment: @JoeSmith The question is tagged Objective-C. Your answer should be in Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: If the authorization status is the same after delete-then-reinstall, then the permission should be honored. What's the concern here?

Comment: Is there any way to reset it so it does show the pop-ups again?

Comment: I am not sure but I believe this is OS behavior. The user, if bothered by this, probably can leverage the reset options in Settings. I don't think the app can do anything about it. It is outside the sandbox.

Comment: Alright what would be the equivalent to getting the camera access pop-up?

Comment: If you are talking about the permission alert, the code in the answer is the way to get it displayed (if needed). You may also go ahead just call photos methods without checking the authorization status, it will also pop up the alert if the status is undetermined (not considered a good practice). If you mean something else, you need to elaborate.

Comment: Yeah that code you supplied shows how to ask permission for photos, but I'd also like to know how to ask permission for camera.